# The problem «Fun game» from a competition

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, greatest-common-divisor

I recently began to learn Python and encountered this problem.

**The condition:**
You and your friends are playing the next game. Friends write  natural numbers in a row on the board. Your task is to find as many consecutive numbers as possible that are divisible by the same number greater than `1`. Since it is difficult to find the answer manually, you decided to write a program that will do the job for you.

**Input:**
The first line of the input contains the number  (`1 ≤  ≤ 100000`). The second line is separated by a space  integers `1`... (`1 ≤  ≤ 1000`, `1 ≤  ≤` ). These are the numbers that your friends wrote. They are given in the same order as they are placed on the board.

**Output:**
Your program should output a single integer — the largest number of consecutive numbers in a given sequence that would be divisible by the same natural number greater than `1`.

**Here is my code:**

```
Python

def func(n,a):

    def gcd(a, b): # Greatest Common Divisor
        return gcd(b, a % b) if b else a

    mx = 0
    for i, cur_g in enumerate(a):
        if n - i < mx:
            break
        p = 0
        for j in range(i, n):
            cur_g = gcd(cur_g, a[j])
            if cur_g == 1:
                break
            p += 1
            if mx < p:
                mx = p

    return mx

print(func(int(input()), [int(i) for i in input().split()]))
```

The problem is that I can't pass the time check: the program runs for longer than 0.5 seconds. And I can't think of any way to speed up the program. It may even be necessary to solve the problem itself in a different way. Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Improving working code is more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I've flagged for migration to CR per [_this meta post_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353)

Comment: Note that Python already has a builtin [``gcd`` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd).